# How to make use of the entire screen area on Android 4.1 in full-screen mode?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, screen, notification-bar

The system bar (aka notification bar) on my new tablet (ASUS Transformer Pad) is always visible, even when watching YouTube "full-screen".

The amount of space wasted is not insignificant, especially when watching a 4:3 video. Is there any way to reclaim it and watch videos/play games in *real* full-screen?

Comment: You are probably talking about the so-called "notification bar". Some apps offer a full-screen mode (which makes that bar disappear). Have you checked the options of the affected apps?

Comment: @Izzy that's the one. I checked the settings of the YouTube app and didn't find such an option.

Comment: OK, so at least the terms are clear. Not having any 4.x device around, I unfortunately cannot offer additional help.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do know it's possible. I have a couple of apps that I with _didn't_ hide the notification bar. I'm afraid it's something the developer is going to need to add in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not intended to hide the system bar (combined soft button/notification bar) on tablets. Imagine the bar is hidden and the app you are currently using does not offer an option to exit. -> Your are stuck within this app.

Some custom ROMs offer the option to hide the bar.

General option would be to use some third-party-apps like [Hide Bottom Bar](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.ppareit.hidebar) or [full!screen](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.tsorn.FullScreenPlus) which can disable the bar somehow. Unfortunately these apps require root.

Comment: Uh...I have a couple of apps that hide the notification bar. (Games, mostly.) So it is possible.

Comment: well "notification bar" might be misunderstood. Romkyns was talking about the system bar on tablets which combines notification area and soft buttons. There is no API-function to hide it since ICS(or HC?). The separate top notification bar which phones have indeed kann be hidden.

Comment: Good to know. I haven't gotten my own Android tablet (yet).

Comment: I guess most people prefer an always-on-screen button to a hardware return button, though I will probably never understand why...

Answer (score 0):

i might not Right at this time but you may use another home screen called **`"Launcher Pro"`** Free version.

In the **setting** there is an **`option to hide the system bar(Notification bar)`**. you can try it out if you like the home screen. though i like it better than stock home screen.

Hope it will some how help you.